# Getting Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection

Tags: r

I am new to R so I am not sure what most of the error messages mean. I am trying to open a data file. However, it sends me an error and I am not sure where it goes wrong.

I tried to put in:

```
library(tidyverse)
airbnb_data <- read.csv("C:/Users/HoaLe's/Desktop/CURRENT QUARTER/225 Data and Society/Homework/hw-02/hw-02/Data/listings.csv")
```

The error message:

```
Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
3.
file(file, "rt")
2.
read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec, fill = fill, comment.char = comment.char, ...)
1.
read.csv("C:/Users/HoaLe's/Desktop/CURRENT QUARTER/\n 225 Data and Society/Homework/hw-02/hw-02/Data/listings.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: there is a space between `QUATER/ 225` it should be `QUATER/225`. Always copy path from file explorer window so you will not go wrong.

Comment: How do I copy the path? Thank you for your help!

Comment: in your file explorer window you will see address bar. Copy path from there. [link](https://cdn.howto-connect.com/wp-content/uploads/Copy-full-path-button-at-the-Home-tab-ribbon.png)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there are linebreaks in the file path (the `\n` in the last error message). Try putting it all on one line:

```
read.csv("C:/Users/HoaLe's/Desktop/CURRENT QUARTER/225 Data and Society/Homework/hw-02/hw-02/Data/listings.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```